# @font-face not working with my Bones Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, font-face

I am trying to get a custom font to work in the Bones Wordpress theme. My font family is in "library > fonts" folder just like theme instructions.

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'ColaborateThinRegular';
        src: url('library/fonts/ColabThi-webfont.eot');
        src: url('library/fonts/ColabThi-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('library/fonts/ColabThi-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
             url('library/fonts/ColabThi-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('library/fonts/ColabThi-webfont.svg#ColaborateThinRegular') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
```

and I call it in my stylesheet like this:

```
    font-family: 'ColaborateThinRegular';
```

I have tried a bunch of different fonts and none work. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on bones and used the relative path to step up one directory to fix it. For you it should be something like this:

```
 @font-face {
        font-family: 'ColaborateThinRegular';
        src: url('../fonts/ColabThi-webfont.eot');
        src: url('../fonts/ColabThi-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('../fonts/ColabThi-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
             url('../fonts/ColabThi-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('../fonts/ColabThi-webfont.svg#ColaborateThinRegular') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
```

Hope this helps!